# Extrude manifold disables loop cuts?

Tags: modeling, extrude, loop

Here's a link to the video where I'm showing the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRtIf1tWLbs

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: you can't loopcut through ngons, only quads

Comment: Ok. How would I then subdivide this face? It seems all functions go away once you use Extrude Manifold. Also weirdly the face orientation gets inverted - is that related?   In other words, I can't subdivide, grid fill, or do anything it seems like.

Comment: to create a new edge loop you can use the knife tool for example, K to activate, A to cut orthogonally, C to cut through

Comment: Unfortunately these kinds of operations are not fully automatic.  Extrude manifold didn't even exist until recently

Comment: Yeah, this is strange how just modelling a simple extruded (or intruded) cube can create many problems. Overlapping faces, can't subdivide, and face orientation gets thrown off very easily. Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: When you model it's better to anticipate the best way to do it in order to avoid any problem, that said it's not hard to fix your topology, as I said you can simply use the knife tool to add edge loops and keep quads. But in your case, if you extrude manifold, it won't create any overlapping or inverted faces

Comment: Yeah, totally. I noticed that when I did this from scratch again, choosing to extrude outward this time, it creates all these inward faces..which, i suppose isn't the worst since i'm not 3d printing this model but geez would be nice to avoid. Because retropology i feel like is harder.